# How to convert string into an variable in python

Tags: python, string, variables, io

I am trying to read an string from a text file. After I read it I want to convert it into an array or variable. In the text file I can read 'b' I sign 'b' to x, `x='b'` ,and I want to use how can I put `'b'` as a variable `b` so that `s = sin(2*pi*x)` is `s = sin(2*pi*b)`.

Object:
I am trying to setup a configure file so that I could easily change the varibles of input from the textfile.

Final step is that I can print it out.

```
b = arange(0.0, 4.0, 0.01)
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
x = ['b'] // result after I read from the file
x = changestringtoVarible('b')

s = sin(2*pi*x)
plot(x, s)
xlabel('time(s)')
ylabel(y)
title(ttl)
grid(True)
```

I want to choose if I use `b` or `t` as xaxis from the text file, that is why I asked this.

Comment: post a sample of your file

Comment: @void I already updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval.

For example:

```
b='4'
formula = "2*x"
formula = formula.replace("x", "%d")
Result = eval(formula % int(b))
```

Comment: please see my upper comment...I didn't get you.

Comment: I think you can use ConfigParser

Comment: Google it. ConfigParser is so easier than you think. You have sections and variables in them. Accessing to them is as easy as defining variable.

Comment: Could you give me a link so that I could get a good one to follow :)

Comment: Hey man! I figure out the answer using the combination of yours and @crs thx u guys

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a primitive form of parsing.  Your variable x will contain the character 'b' or 't', and you want use that to control how an expression is evaluated.  You can't use the variable x directly in the expression, because it just contains a character.  You have to execute different code depending on its value.  For a simple case like this, you can just use an `if` construct:

```
...
b = arange(0.0, 4.0, 0.01)
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

if x == 'b':
    xvalue = b
elif x == 't'
    xvalue = t

s = sin(2*pi*xvalue)
plot(xvalue, s)
...
```

For a larger number of cases, you can use a dictionary:

```
...
xvalues = { 'b' : arange(0.0, 4.0, 0.01),
            't' : arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01),
            # More values here
          }

xvalue = xvalues[x]
s = sin(2*pi*xvalue)
plot(xvalue, s)
....
```

Comment: Ok Let me explain in this way, if there is so many varibles to choose, it doesn't make sense to use if else statement. Because I am trying to setup a configure file so that I could easily change the varibles of input from the textfile.

Comment: I am doing a big project, if the varible is store in other files, I couldn't do this, like 2000 variables.

Comment: For a such a large number, @Farhadix's answer is better.

Comment: Thx for your effort, i up your solution also!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a string as a variable you can use pythons exec function:

```
>>> exec("some_string"+"=1234")
>>> some_string
1234
```

**update:**

You better want to use another name for the `x` variable in `s = sin(2*pi*x)`, we might call `x` `y` from now on.

```
b = arange(0.0, 4.0, 0.01)
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
```

Assumed that `x` defines which one should be used, you can use the following code to assign it to a variable:

```
exec("y"+"="+x)
s = sin(2*pi*y)
```

That one should work. But i would recommend you to change you code to something more solid (e.g. using a dictionary).

Comment: Because I am trying to setup a configure file so that I could easily change the varibles of input from the textfile. I want to do x = b, and use it as input. could you please try it on my code? I tried but it doesn't work...

Comment: Please write complete sentences.Otherwise no one knows what you are trying to tell us.

Comment: if i do exec("y"+"="+"b") it works perfectly, but I have to do exec("y"+"="+x) it doesn't work. if I do exec("y"+"="+'x') it will return y = 'b' instead of y=b.

Comment: hey, thx man! I first set up an ConfigParser file and configer it, the input is a string instead of the list of string, now I use your strategy to solve it.